# Register user without changing currentUser.uid

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an app where parents create accounts for their children and their child's info is linked to their account in the realtime database. My realtime database rules are set so the `currentUser.uid` must match the uid of the parent's database entry. I'm getting access denied when trying to create the child node in the database because `Auth.auth().currentUser` is being changed to the newly created user.

How can I create a user without changing the currently logged in user?

```
func registerUser(with email: String, and password: String, registrationComplete: @escaping (_ status: Bool, _ error: Error?, _ user: User?) -> Void) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email,
                           password: password) { (result, error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                registrationComplete(false, error, nil)
                                return
                            }
                            registrationComplete(true, nil, result?.user)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `createUser` in client code, that implicitly signs out the current user and signs in a new user.  There is no way to avoid this behavior.

What you should do instead is involve some backend code.  Your client app should call a backend that uses the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), which can [create the new account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) without affecting the currently signed in user in the client app.  Many developers choose Cloud Functions for this, as it doesn't involve setting up an actual servers.